# Excel VBA UserForm converting "," to "."

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am having trouble on calculation in UserForm in VBA for Excel.

I define a variable `x As Long` and then I give the value from a specific sheet. Then that value is used in calculation inside the code and afterwards it is been displayed in combobox.

I have an error calculation when I switch from English windows to German Windows version and I can not fix it since the comma is decimal separator and dot is thousand.

How can I create a universal calculation regardless of what system language is?
Best regards and thanks in advance.

You can see the code below, and the cell is formated as number with 2 decimals and it doesn't use thousand separator:

Lets asume that "C24".value=-763.54

```
Dim x As Long
x = eko_bau.Range("C24").Value
Me.GWP_A.Text = x
```

And then insted of showing `-763.54` it shows `-76354`

Comment: Are you considering the dot in `-763.54` to be a thousand seperator or a mathematic comma? What is the result of `Debug.Print eko_bau.Range("C24").Value`? What is your systems (Windows) comma and thousands operator?

Comment: A `Long` is a long integer - no decimals. Change data type to `Double`

Comment: @FunThomas there must be something else wrong. Pushing a decimal into a `Long` will truncate the decimal digits and not just remove the seperator.

Comment: search around locale settings, such as: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/region-language.htm

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Problably. But I don't know what. I assume OP doesn't show the full truth. If cell contains a numeric value, x would be 763 (independent of the regional settings). If it contains a string (that looks like a number), it would either be 763 or throw a runtime error. Anyhow, to dig into the problem, first thing is to use the correct data type

Comment: @FunThomas The only that would match what the OP describes is: Decimal seperator is set to comma the value in the cell is `-763.54` (as text NOT numeric). If you then cast this string into a long you get `-76354` (like `Debug.Print cLng("-763.54")`) shows. So the actual problem is that the *"number"* in the cell is text and not numeric. Therefore the actual question to the OP must be: How did the *"number"* get into that cell?

Comment: @АлександарМитић Where do the values in the cell come from? How did they get there? Were they somehow imported?

Comment: This result -763.54 should be displayed in combobx value(Me.GWP_A.text or Me.GWP_A.value). And in that case dot should be decimal separator, because i noticed that values that are displayed in userform are always with dot as decimal separator. Now i am using German windows so comma is decimal separator and dot is thousand. I can not see debug.print.

Comment: @Александар Митић If -763.54 is text formatted, how can it be affected by localization? Do you try saying that it is a number? In this case, localization should change it in -763,54. Being it declared as Double, it should be shown correctly.

Comment: If the userform shows always dots even if the decimal separator is a comme your entire code needs to be adjusted and is probably not able to work with multiple localizations. The other work arround is to set the decimal separator to `.` in Excel (see [Change the character used to separate thousands or decimals](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)

Comment: Now after using double for variable it gave me better result. Thank you. I thought the long can be also used for those values.

Comment: Once again Thank you all so much. Now with this code it working really good:
Dim x As Double
x = eko_bau.Range("C24").Value
Me.GWP_A.Value = x

And then when i am saving this value to a cell it is like this:
sheet1Range("D24").Value = CDbl(Me.GWP_A.Value)
'''Here Me.GWP is combobox'''''